# Saving and sorting dates in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm saving a date in a document the following way (NodeJS and Javascript driver for MongoDB):

```
my_data: {
    my_date: new Date()
}
db.collection("my_test_collection").save(my_data, {w: 0});
```

When I query the data from `my_test_collection` I see that `my_date` is actually a `String` and it looks like: `2013-09-23T10:46:01.914Z`

1. Does this matter?
2. How do I sort my query by this field?

I tried `....find().sort(['my_date', 'asc'])` but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What did you expect it to be?

Comment: @Amberlamps A date maybe? That's why I'm asking if it matters, aka, if it should have some other type or being a string is fine.

Comment: Being a string is fine. Convert it back to a Date object when querying data `var my_date = new Date("2013-09-23T10:46:01.914Z")`.

Comment: @Amberlamps I wasn't asking how to get it back to a date. I was asking how to sort my documents on that date field.

Comment: I don’t know how the Node.js driver works, but MongoDB does have a datatype for date/time, it can store and sort things with this datatype. With the Python driver, this works transparently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't matter that its returning the date to you like that.

You should be able to sort through it like so:

```
db.my_test_collection.find().sort({'my_date':1})pe
```

If you wish to sort by descending simply change the 1 to -1 like so:

```
db.my_test_collection.find().sort({'my_date':-1})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was sorting by two fields, and I was sorting the date as the second one, so that's why it wasn't working. Thanks :)

Comment: Not a problem.  Multiple fields is essentially the same.  .sort({'field1':1, 'field2':1})

Comment: Yes, the thing is that it was sorting alphabelically first, then by date. That's why my dates where in the wrong order.